# Configure `git add -p` to split hunk on newlines?

Tags: git

If I have a file with two lines separated by a newline:

```
$ cat file.txt
foo

bar
```

And it has outstanding changes in my repo:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index e69de29..2db72cd 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+foo
+
+bar
```

Trying to add it with `-p` and split the hunk fails:

```
$ git add -p file.txt
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index e69de29..2db72cd 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+foo
+
+bar
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? s
Sorry, cannot split this hunk
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+foo
+
+bar
(1/1) Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]?
```

Can I configure git to allow me to split this hunk on newlines?

I know that I can edit the patch instead, but I'd like to avoid that.

**Bonus:** Can I configure git to allow me to split on decreasing amounts of newlines? I.e., first it splits on double newlines, then single newlines?

Comment: Git seems to be considering those lines as a single change. It’s likely because they’re too close to each other

Comment: Yes, unchanged lines are required between changed lines for git to be able to automatically split the patch. I'm asking if it's possible to change that.

Comment: You can edit the hunk, but you may need to change `@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@`

Comment: @evolutionxbox you are supposed to just be able to delete the added lines; Git should re-count the headers automatically. Some versions of `git add -p` have a bug where you can't edit any patch that's at the top of the file, though.

Comment: The short answer is "no, you can't do that". The Git folks are adding a new style of patching that might let you do that eventually, maybe, as part of an effort to depend less on Perl. If you're good with Perl programming, though, you can hack on `git add -p`, which is really a Perl script.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I'm aware, in the question I said "I know that I can edit the patch instead, but I'd like to avoid that."

Comment: @torek Thanks, I figured that'd be the answer. Can you provide any pointers to the "new style of patching" work? Just curious.

Comment: No, I just remember seeing something somewhere, maybe in `git log` output, maybe in a release notes file.